# How to add a reference to NetStandard2.0 or 2.1?

Tags: .net-framework-version

I have a WinForms application using .NET Framework 4.7.2, which uses a library that targets NetStandard2.0 and 2.1. While the library does seem to load, I get an exception when the library is called, saying "Error could not find assembly netstandard2.1 file not found". I assume that I need to add a reference from the application to NetStandard2.1. Is that correct? How do I do this?

Comment: That's not possible, the legacy framework only supports .NETStandard 2.0

Comment: Can I add a reference to NetStandard 2.0? How to do that?

Comment: No, do not add a reference.  The phrase "that targets NetStandard2.0 and 2.1" is nonsensical, a library targets 2.0 or 2.1, not both.  Right now you've got a version that requires 2.1, you'll have to find a version that targets 2.0.  Ask the library author for assistance, the answer may well be "that's not possible".

Comment: The library project file had the following.
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.1;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
I've modified the library to target only 2.0
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
and rebuilt it and now the app seems to work.